# A uniform copy and move constructor of a template class

Tags: c++, c++17

Let assume I have a DataProcessor template class that holds a smart pointer to the processed data that has operator * and operator ->:

```
template <class DataPointer>
class DataProcessor
{
    public:

        //it is not clear how to implement the constructor
        //DataProcessor(DataPointer p) : pData(p) {};

        void Process() { /* do something with *pData */ };

    private:

        DataPointer pData;
}
```

How to implement the constructor to make DataProcessor work with both std::unique_ptr (the constructor should accept it by && and move it) and std::shared_ptr (the constructor should accept it by & and copy it)? Is it possible to have some kind of a uniform constructor?

Actually I have a class that holds a smart Win32 handle UniqueHandle and SharedHandle that have the similar semantics like std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr. So it is a general question on how to implement a scenario like this.

Comment: "*std::shared_ptr (the constructor should accept it by & and copy it)?*" Why should the constructor copy it? Why not take it by `&&` and have the caller perform the copy?

Comment: @NicolBolas this adds one extra line of code, but probably it is better than having two separate classes like UniqueDataProcessor and SharedDataProcessor with different constructors taking && and &.

Comment: It is impossible to take ownership of an object owned by a `shared_ptr`. So, unless `DataPointer` is actually also a `shared_ptr`, you have a lost case.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky: "*this adds one extra line of code*" Nonsense: `DataProcessor<shared_ptr<T>> dp(shared_ptr{sp});` Where `sp` is an appropriate shared_ptr (and using CTAD to avoid repeating the `T`). No extra line of code needed.

Comment: @NicolBolas at least I did not find a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choices are essentially these:

1. Take the parameter by value:

   ```
   DataProcessor(DataPointer p) : pData(std::move(p)) {}
   ```

   If `DataPointer` is move-only, then the user will have to call it through `std::move`, which will move-construct `p`, which is then used to move-construct `pData`. If it is copyable, then `p` will be copy/move constructed based on how the user passes the value. From there, it will move construct `pData`.

   Note that this version adds an additional move operation.
2. Take the parameter by rvalue reference, always:

   ```
   DataProcessor(DataPointer &&p) : pData(std::move(p)) {}
   ```

   In this case, if `DataPointer` is not move-only, and the user wants to pass an lvalue, the user must explicitly copy the value into a temporary used to initialize `p`. That would look something like this:

   ```
   DataProcessor<shared_ptr<T>> dp(shared_ptr{sp});
   ```

   Where `sp` is an existing `shared_ptr` that you want to copy from. This does only one move when given an object to move from, but does a copy+move when copying.
3. Write two functions, employing SFINAE to remove the copying version if `DataPointer` is non-copyable. This version has the advantage of doing no additional moves:

```
DataProcessor(DataPointer &&p) : pData(std::move(p)) {}
template<typename T = DataPointer>
DataProcessor(std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>, const T&> p)
        : pData(p) {}
```

Comment: IMHO 3 looks better than 1 and 2